# How to get everything before the dash character in regex?

Tags: regex

I have strings of the following form:

```
en-US //return en

en-UK //return en

en //don't return

nl-NL //return nl

nl-BE //return nl

nl //don't return
```

I would like to return the one's that are indicated in the code above. I tried `.*\-` but this returns `en-`. How do I stop returning before the slash? So only return `en`? I'm testing it [here](https://regex101.com/r/kUQVKd/1).

Comment: You might as well use `^([^-]+)-` and grab the Group 1 value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead.

```
.*(?=-)
```

If you are always specifically looking for 2 lowercase alpha characters preceeding a dash, then it is probably a good idea to be a bit more targeted with your regex.

```
[a-z]{2}(?=-)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a capturing group at the start of the string for the first 2 lowercase chars and then match the following  dash and the 2 uppercase chars.

```
^([a-z]{2})-[A-Z]{2}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DQSbui/1)

If you want to capture multiple chars `[a-z]` (or any character except a hypen or newline `[^-\r\n]`) before the dash and then match it you could use a quantifier like `+` to match 1+ times or use `{2,}` to match 2 or more times.

```
^([a-z]{2,})-
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0wQFq2/1)

Comment: but this doesn't work when there are more than two chars, but maybe I wasn't clear that this was possible as well.

Answer (score 1):

`.+?(?=-)` as a regular expression should do what you are asking.

Where

`.` matches any character

`+?` matches between one and infinity times, but it does it as few times as possible, using lazy expansion

and

`(?=-)` Is a positive look ahead, so it checks ahead in the string, and only matches and returns if the next character in the string is `-` but the return will not include the value `-`